# Javascript check if first character is number, upperCase, lowerCase or special character

Tags: javascript, special-characters, uppercase, lowercase

The goal is a program that checks if the first character they type is a number, uppercase letter,
lowercase letter or a special character/other.

Number works absolutely fine, but my task **has to compare** the uppercase and lowercase and check if they are letters. If not, it should then return special character. I also have to make it without using functions.

I am struggling to get the special character to display as it is treated as either uppercase or lowercase.
I have tried fiddling around with the equals signs and using regex but I am confusing myself. onlyLetters as you can see it not being used as I have tried making it == to input.
Doing this led to everything (except numbers) being shown as a special character and thus reversing the problem.
I have also tried seeing what works for others but they do not work on uppercase and lowercase letters also like I am.

Is there way to return an uppercase letter, lowercase letter or special character without the use of a function?
Help to restore sanity is greatly appreciated

```js
let input = prompt('Enter a number or uppercase or lowercase letter')
let onlyLetters = /^[a-zA-Z]/
const upperCase = input.toUpperCase()
const lowerCase = input.toLowerCase()
const numInput = Number(input)

if (Number.isInteger(numInput) == true) {
  console.log(input + ' is a number')
} else if (input === upperCase || lowerCase) {
  if (input === upperCase) {
    console.log(input + ' is an uppercase letter')
  } else if (input === lowerCase) {
    console.log(input + ' is a lowercase letter')
  }
} else {
  console.log(input + ' is a special character')
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using ASCII codes? Since your input is a string/char, it will already be encoded as ASCII, and you can simply compare the ASCII number against known ranges to determine what kind of character it is.

Comment: Ah I didn't think to use ASCII. Thanks I'll look into it!

Comment: without using functions how?, I get lost in that part, or try the ascii codes as @Stitt says, just take a look how eg: how the char type works

Comment: @Stritt using ASCII worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an error here

`if (input === upperCase || lowerCase) {`

should be

`if (input === upperCase || input === lowerCase) {`

But just use the regex you had but did not use

```js
let input = prompt('Enter a number or uppercase or lowercase letter')
const numInput = Number(input)

if (Number.isInteger(numInput)) {
  console.log(input + ' is a number')
} else if (input.match(/[a-zA-Z]/)) {
  const upperCase = input.toUpperCase()
  const lowerCase = input.toLowerCase()
  if (input === upperCase) {
    console.log(input + ' is an uppercase letter')
  } else if (input === lowerCase) {
    console.log(input + ' is a lowercase letter')
  }
} else {
  console.log(input + ' is a special character')
}
```

Comment: Knowing how to do it with regex is valuable knowledge. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I made Uppercase and Lowercase check for ASCII values instead.
That way if it is not an ASCII value it can go to the else statement and return a special character.

```
let input = prompt('Enter a number or uppercase or lowercase letter')
const upperCase = input.toUpperCase()
const lowerCase = input.toLowerCase()
const numInput = Number(input)
charCode = input.charCodeAt(0)

if (Number.isInteger(numInput) == true) {
    console.log( input + ' is a number')
}

// 65 to 90 for uppercase
// 97 to 122 for lowercase

else if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <=90) {
    console.log(input + ' is an uppercase letter')
}

else if (charCode >= 97 && charCode <=122) {
    console.log(input + ' is a lowercase letter')
}

else {
    console.log(input + ' is a special character')
}
```